# Retrofit: @QueryName and varargs

Tags: retrofit2

Example:

```
@GET("/friends")
Call<ResponseBody> friends(@QueryName String... filters);
```

Calling with `foo.friends("contains(Bob)", "age(42)")`

and result =  `/friends?contains(Bob)&age(42)`

OK, it's work fine.

But I need the next result:

```
/friends?page=1&age=42&county=USA
```

is it possible by varargs `@QueryName String... filters`  ?

Comment: why not use QueryMap instead?

Comment: With "QueryMap" is work , but .. the problem with "QueryMap" is that client code know about param names (encapsulation violation)

Comment: that is not something you should worry about. Make sure things on the server side are secure enough.